# One Signal setup not match with current firebase dependencies

Tags: flutter, dart, plugins, onesignal

I try to prepare my flutter app to work with one signal plugin , but when follow the steps that defined by one signal itself , there are many error related to version of dependancies appear I upgrade them but the problem is still exist and  not clear for me

````
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> In project 'android' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[1
  0.2.1, 16.0.99]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the library will be unknown.

  Dependency failing: com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.15.6 -> com.google.android.gms:play-services-location@[10.2.1, 16.0.99], b
  ut play-services-location version was 17.1.0.

  The following dependencies are project dependencies that are direct or have transitive dependencies that lead to the art
  ifact with the issue.
  -- Project 'android' depends on project 'geolocator' which depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-location@16
  .0.0
  -- Project 'android' depends on project 'app' which depends onto com.onesignal:OneSignal@[3.15.6, 3.99.99]
  -- Project 'android' depends on project 'app' which depends onto com.onesignal:OneSignal@{strictly 3.15.6}
  -- Project 'android' depends on project 'onesignal_flutter' which depends onto com.onesignal:OneSignal@3.15.6
  -- Project 'android' depends on project 'app' which depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-location@17.1.0
  -- Project 'android' depends on project 'app' which depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-location@{strictly
   17.1.0}
  -- Project 'android' depends on project 'location' which depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-location@16.+

  For extended debugging info execute Gradle from the command line with ./gradlew --info :android:assembleDebug to see the
   dependency paths to the artifact. This error message came from the google-services Gradle plugin, report issues at http
  s://github.com/google/play-services-plugins and disable by adding "googleServices { disableVersionCheck = true }" to you
  r build.gradle file.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights. ```
````

Comment: Are you using this? https://pub.dev/packages/onesignal_flutter

Comment: yes I use this plugin within the official instructions

Answer (score 0):

May be this issue arise because your project not match with this version of library ,

Try to use this way(default version)

```
onesignal_flutter:
```

Not this way

```
onesignal_flutter: ^2.6.2
```